# Masking out shadows in Sentinel images using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

This question is an addition to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272224/how-do-i-create-a-sentinel-2-cloud-free-cloud-shadow-free-composite-or-scene-on/272325#272325) to [Creating Sentinel-2 cloud free, cloud-shadow free composite or scene on Google Earth Engine (GEE)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/272224/115)

There Rodrigo E. Principe showed how to mask out the clouds. I am wondering if there is a way to mask the shadows as well. And, if possible then not only the shadows of the clouds but also, shadows in rugged topography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been an approach to do this using a decision tree: [Ready-to-Use Methods for the Detection of Clouds, Cirrus, Snow, Shadow, Water and Clear Sky Pixels in Sentinel-2 MSI Images](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/8/666/pdf).

I have adapted the code to EE, and make it open source in `geetools`, both for the [Python API](https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools) and for the [JavaScript API](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor)

```js
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks')
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20151123T142942_20170221T180430_T19GCN')

Map.centerObject(image)

var mask_shadow = cld.hollstein_S2(['shadow'])(image)

Map.addLayer(mask_shadow, {bands:['B8', 'B11','B4'], min:0, max:5000})
```