# Is there a way to interpolate lost data/lost pixels caused by cloud and cloud shadow masks in Google Earth Engine? WITHOUT editing filter(Date)

Tags: google-earth-engine, interpolation, masking, pixel, cloud-cover

I'm sure cloud and cloud shadows have been, time and time again, a frustrating problem. Usually after masking the two, I composite multiple images (in a set time interval e.g. 2015-2016, months 6-8) and that solves the missing pixels caused by the masking.

Sometimes though it doesn't quite work.

**Is there a way to interpolate lost data/lost pixels caused by cloud and cloud shadow masking in Google Earth Engine?**

[image: False Color Image of Study Area, those encircled are the missing pixels]

Comment: I think this will solve it: [link to question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323728/smoothing-interpolating-across-images-in-an-imagecollection-to-remove-missing-da/323819#323819). Just change the filterDate() in the variable meanImage to advance 1 or more years.